# dont get the point of prove stabilizer

Tags: abstract-algebra

$g^{-1}\cdot x=g^{-1}\cdot(g\cdot x)=(g^{-1}g)\cdot x=1_G\cdot x=x\;$

Can someone explain me that prove $g^{-1} \in$ Stabilizer. Why do this right this?

Comment: The left most side $g^{-1}x$ is equal to the rightmost side, $x$. So by definition $g^{-1}$ stabilizes $x$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g\cdot x = x$.
Then you get $g^{-1}\cdot x = g^{-1}\cdot(g\cdot x)$.
By the definition of group operation, this equals $(g^{-1}\cdot g)\cdot x$ and this equals in turn $1_G\cdot g$. By the definition of group operation, this equals $x$.